# Why won't the Office 2007 AutoCorrections feature install correctly?

Tags: windows-installer

I've installed Office 2007 successfully but each time I use an application that requires spell checking (e.g. Word, Outlook) I begin typing and get the following message

The list of common English (U.K.) AutoCorrections is not available. This feature is not currently installed. Would you like to install it now?

If I click Yes, I get an error with the message

The list of common English (U.K.) AutoCorrections is not available. Microsoft Office Outlook cannot install the necessary files due to Windows Installer error 1605. This action is only valid for products that are currently installed.

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this? A reinstall hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3386618.php

This worked for me. Delete the referenced at the site and it should do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't work for me and seems to be the only fix on multiple sites. Has anyone else any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

copy a good MSO2057.acl from admin user profile to users\"username"\appdata\microsoft\office. Overwrite the one that is there. Relogon on as user. You mayalso have to copy it to the roaming profile.